# How to display a loading animated gif while a code is executing in backend of my Python Qt5 UI?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qt5, loading

**Environment:**

Python 3.7

Qt5

Windows 10

**Problem:**

When I execute my code, it shows immediately the UI, then it supposes to make some other preparing stuff and display a loading gif while these initialization tasks are running. But it does work. Instead of showing the gif, the UI is blocked(froze) waiting for my preparing script to finish its job.

My script has a button to Run my main script "StartMyApp" and show an animated gif while MyApp is running without freezing my UI. I use multithread for this purpose. It works perfectly. I used this tutorial : https://www.learnpyqt.com/courses/concurrent-execution/multithreading-pyqt-applications-qthreadpool/

So I thought by cloning the same logic, I could display another loading gif at the **init** of my UI but it didn't work. I missed something. I don't understand because the "Run" button works perfectly by showing the gif and running the main code without freezing the UI whereas my "preparing" code is not showing the gif and freezing my UI until it finishes.

Does anyone understand the source of this issue?

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QMovie
import traceback, sys
class WorkerSignals(QObject):
    '''
    Defines the signals available from a running worker thread.

    Supported signals are:

    finished
        No data

    error
        `tuple` (exctype, value, traceback.format_exc() )

    result
        `object` data returned from processing, anything

    progress
        `int` indicating % progress

    '''
    finished = pyqtSignal ()
    error = pyqtSignal (tuple)
    result = pyqtSignal (object)
    progress = pyqtSignal (int)



class Worker (QRunnable):
    '''
    Worker thread

    Inherits from QRunnable to handler worker thread setup, signals and wrap-up.

    :param callback: The function callback to run on this worker thread. Supplied args and
                     kwargs will be passed through to the runner.
    :type callback: function
    :param args: Arguments to pass to the callback function
    :param kwargs: Keywords to pass to the callback function

    '''

    def __init__(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
        super (Worker, self).__init__ ()

        # Store constructor arguments (re-used for processing)
        self.fn = fn
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.signals = WorkerSignals ()

        # Add the callback to our kwargs
        self.kwargs['progress_callback'] = self.signals.progress

    @pyqtSlot ()
    def run(self):
        '''
        Initialise the runner function with passed args, kwargs.
        '''

        # Retrieve args/kwargs here; and fire processing using them
        try:
            result = self.fn (*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        except:
            traceback.print_exc ()
            exctype, value = sys.exc_info ()[:2]
            self.signals.error.emit((exctype, value, traceback.format_exc ()))
        else:
            self.signals.result.emit (result)  # Return the result of the processing
        finally:
            self.signals.finished.emit ()  # Done


class Ui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        
        super(Ui, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('Ui/MyAppUI.Ui', self)
        # === We display the UI ==========
        self.show()
        # === THis will handle the MULTITHREAD PART ===================
        self.threadpool = QThreadPool()
        print("Multithreading with maximum %d threads" % self.threadpool.maxThreadCount())

        self.StartPreparingMyApp() #<======== This method doesn't work!!!!

        # === Associate methods to the buttons of the UI ==============        
        self.button_Report.clicked.connect (self.ButtonStartMyAppReport)        
        self.button_Run.clicked.connect (self.ButtonStartMyApp)
    
    def StartMyAppReport(self, progress_callback):
        #do some stuff

    def StartMyApp(self, progress_callback):
        # do some stuff

    def ButtonStartMyApp(self): #<=== This method works perfectly by showing the loading gif.
        # Pass the function to execute
        # === We need to block the Button Run and change its color
        self.button_Run.setEnabled (False)
        self.button_Run.setText ('Running...')
        self.button_Run.setStyleSheet ("background-color: #ffcc00;")
        self.label_logo.setHidden (True)
        self.label_running.setHidden (False)

        # === Play animated gif ================
        self.gif = QMovie ('ui/animated_gif_logo_UI_.gif')
        self.label_running.setMovie (self.gif)
        self.gif.start ()

        self.EditTextFieldUi (self.label_HeaderMsg1, '#ff8a00',
                              "MyApp is running the tasks... You can press the button 'Report' to see what MyApp has done.")
        self.EditTextFieldUi (self.label_HeaderMsg2, '#ff8a00',
                              "Press 'button 'Quit' to stop and turn off MyApp.")

        worker = Worker (self.StartMyApp)  # Any other args, kwargs are passed to the run function
        worker.signals.result.connect (self.print_output)
        worker.signals.finished.connect (self.thread_complete)
        worker.signals.progress.connect (self.progress_fn)

        # Execute
        self.threadpool.start (worker)

    def PreparingMyApp(self, progress_callback):
        #do some stuff
        return "Done"
    
    def ButtonStartMyAppReport(self):
        # Pass the function to execute
        worker = Worker (self.StartMyAppReport)  # Any other args, kwargs are passed to the run function
        worker.signals.result.connect (self.print_output)
        worker.signals.finished.connect (self.thread_complete)
        worker.signals.progress.connect (self.progress_fn)

        # Execute
        self.threadpool.start(worker)
        

    def StartPreparingMyApp(self): #<=== This method doesn't work !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        # === Play animated gif ================
        self.label_loading.setHidden (False)
        self.gif_loading = QMovie ('ui/loading.gif')
        self.label_loading.setMovie (self.gif_loading)
        self.gif_loading.start ()

        # Pass the function to execute
        worker = Worker (self.PreparingMyApp)  # Any other args, kwargs are passed to the run function
        worker.signals.result.connect (self.print_output)
        worker.signals.finished.connect (self.thread_complete)
        worker.signals.progress.connect (self.progress_fn)

        # Execute
        self.threadpool.start (worker)

        self.gif_loading.stop ()
        self.label_loading.setHidden (True)

        
if __name__ == '__main__':    
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Ui()
    app.exec_()
```

**Edit:**

I added the xml source of MyAppUI.ui made with Qt Designer in order to reproduce my example:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U9x0NmZ7GP6plzvRb6YgwIqaFHCz1PMc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You forgot to publish the module `MyAppUI.Ui`.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. What do you mean? I have this line at the very bottom :window = Ui()

Comment: Copy what you published to a new directory and try running the application. Your example is not reproducible.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. When I run this code, it loads the UI and runs the preparing script. The problem is it doesn't show the loading gif and UI is froze while the preparing script is running. Could you please be more accurate by saying "what you published"? Did you mean all the code? Did you mean the MyAppUI?

Comment: MyAppUI.Ui was done with Qt Designer.

Comment: Would you like the python code source of MyAppUI.Ui or the XML source code of it? Will it help you?

Comment: I added the XML source of MyAppUI.ui in order to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything works for you.
Please note that I transferred

```
self.gif_loading.stop()             # <---- +++
self.label_loading.setHidden(True)  # <---- +++
```

in the `thread_complete` method and added `QtCore.QThread.msleep (5000)`
into the `run` method to observe the process of `self.gif_loading`

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui, uic
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class WorkerSignals(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal ()
    error = pyqtSignal (tuple)
    result = pyqtSignal (object)
    progress = pyqtSignal (int)


class Worker (QRunnable):
    def __init__(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
        super (Worker, self).__init__ ()

        # Store constructor arguments (re-used for processing)
        self.fn = fn
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.signals = WorkerSignals ()

        # Add the callback to our kwargs
        self.kwargs['progress_callback'] = self.signals.progress

    @pyqtSlot ()
    def run(self):
        '''
        Initialise the runner function with passed args, kwargs.
        '''

        # Retrieve args/kwargs here; and fire processing using them
        try:
            result = self.fn (*self.args, **self.kwargs)
            
            QtCore.QThread.msleep(5000)                        #   +++ !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            
        except:
            traceback.print_exc ()
            exctype, value = sys.exc_info ()[:2]
            self.signals.error.emit((exctype, value, traceback.format_exc ()))
        else:
            self.signals.result.emit (result)  # Return the result of the processing
        finally:
            self.signals.finished.emit ()      # Done


class Ui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        
        super(Ui, self).__init__()
        
#        uic.loadUi('Ui/MyAppUI.Ui', self)                                # !!!
        uic.loadUi('my_app_ui.ui', self)                                  # !!!
        
        # === We display the UI ==========
        self.show()
        # === THis will handle the MULTITHREAD PART ===================
        self.threadpool = QThreadPool()
        print("Multithreading with maximum %d threads" % self.threadpool.maxThreadCount())

        self.StartPreparingMyApp()                       # <======== This method  work !!!!

        # === Associate methods to the buttons of the UI ==============        
        self.button_Report.clicked.connect (self.ButtonStartMyAppReport)        
        self.button_Run.clicked.connect (self.ButtonStartMyApp)
    
    def StartMyAppReport(self, progress_callback):
        #do some stuff
        pass                                                             # +++

    def StartMyApp(self, progress_callback):
        # do some stuff
        pass                                                             # +++

    def ButtonStartMyApp(self): #<=== This method works perfectly by showing the loading gif.
        # Pass the function to execute
        # === We need to block the Button Run and change its color
        self.button_Run.setEnabled (False)
        self.button_Run.setText ('Running...')
        self.button_Run.setStyleSheet ("background-color: #ffcc00;")
        self.label_logo.setHidden (True)
        self.label_running.setHidden (False)

        # === Play animated gif ================
        self.gif = QMovie("D:/_Qt/__Qt/wait.gif")          # ('ui/animated_gif_logo_UI_.gif') !!!
        self.label_running.setMovie (self.gif)
        self.gif.start ()

#?        self.EditTextFieldUi (self.label_HeaderMsg1, '#ff8a00',
#?                              "MyApp is running the tasks... You can press the button 'Report' to see what MyApp has done.")
#?        self.EditTextFieldUi (self.label_HeaderMsg2, '#ff8a00',
#?                              "Press 'button 'Quit' to stop and turn off MyApp.")

        worker = Worker (self.StartMyApp)  # Any other args, kwargs are passed to the run function
        worker.signals.result.connect (self.print_output)
        worker.signals.finished.connect (self.thread_complete)
        worker.signals.progress.connect (self.progress_fn)

        # Execute
        self.threadpool.start (worker)

    def PreparingMyApp(self, progress_callback):
        #do some stuff
        return "Done"
    
    def ButtonStartMyAppReport(self):
        # Pass the function to execute
        worker = Worker (self.StartMyAppReport)  # Any other args, kwargs are passed to the run function
        worker.signals.result.connect (self.print_output)
        worker.signals.finished.connect (self.thread_complete)
        worker.signals.progress.connect (self.progress_fn)

        # Execute
        self.threadpool.start(worker)
        
    def StartPreparingMyApp(self): 
        print("!!! <=== This method work !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
        # === Play animated gif ================
        self.label_loading.setHidden (False)
        self.gif_loading = QMovie("D:/_Qt/__Qt/wait.gif")        # ('ui/loading.gif') !!!
        self.label_loading.setMovie (self.gif_loading)
        self.gif_loading.start ()

        # Pass the function to execute
        worker = Worker (self.PreparingMyApp)  # Any other args, kwargs are passed to the run function
        worker.signals.result.connect (self.print_output)
        worker.signals.finished.connect (self.thread_complete)
        worker.signals.progress.connect (self.progress_fn)

        # Execute
        self.threadpool.start (worker)

#        self.gif_loading.stop ()                                # ---
#        self.label_loading.setHidden (True)                     # ---
        
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv    
    def print_output(self, obj):
        print(f'def print_output(self, obj): {obj}')    
        
    def thread_complete(self, val='finished'):
        print(f'def thread_complete(self, obj): {val}') 
        self.gif_loading.stop ()                                  # <---- +++
        self.label_loading.setHidden (True)                       # <---- +++        
        
    def progress_fn(self, val):
        print(f'def progress_fn(self, obj): {val}')  
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        

        
if __name__ == '__main__':    
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Ui()
    app.exec_()
```

[image]